# Swap two elements in elm Array

Tags: arrays, swap, elm

I would like to do a function to swap two elements in array.

Obviously if it is triggered `Up` msg with first element, nothing will happens. Same if `Down` msg with latest element.

I have the following code:

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, button, div, text)
import Html.Attributes exposing (class)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)
import Array
import List exposing (map)

type alias Model = Array.Array Int


initialModel : Model
initialModel =
    Array.fromList [3, 1, 7, 2, 6, 4, 5]


type Msg
    = Up Int
    | Down Int


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Up n ->
           swap model n (n-1)
        Down n ->
           swap model n (n+1)

swap : Model -> Int -> Int -> Model
swap model src dest =
   model -- How do it?


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div [] (map elements (Array.toIndexedList model))

elements : (Int, Int) -> Html Msg
elements (position, number) =
  div [ class "block" ]
    [ button [ onClick (Up position) ] [ text "UP" ]
    , div [] [ text <| String.fromInt number ]
    , button [ onClick (Down position) ] [ text "DOWN" ]
    ]


main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.sandbox
        { init = initialModel
        , view = view
        , update = update
        }
```

**And I would like to know if it is better using List or Array to do that.**

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would generally prefer to use a List instead of Array, but if you don't plan to add new items to your list, an Array would likely make more sense.

A pro of Array is that accessing a specific element is faster, but if you only have a few items you probably won't have to worry about performance. Also converting from Array to List is also not without performance costs.

**Option 1: If you keep using an Array**, you could solve it e.g. like this:

1. [Get the values](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Array#get) at `src` and `dest` and bail early if one of them returns `Nothing` (this will cover the cases where a index is out of bounds)
2. [Set the value](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Array#set) of src to dest and the other way around
3. Return the new array

**Option 2: If you use a List instead**, you could for instance use the [elm-community/list-extra](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/latest/List-Extra#swapAt) package.
It has a [swapAt](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/latest/List-Extra#swapAt) function that does what you need.

**Option 3: Can be implemented for either List or Array**, but you will need to implement a custom behavior that traverses all the elements and builds a new Array/List, which is out of scope for now I think.

Regards,
marc